# How to vectorize a function for each ID# in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-munging

This method is time/cpu intensive and there's got to be a better way! Can someone help me vectorize the following code without using a loop?  Basically, I have a df where each subject has multiple rows, and each row has a value. I want to add a column that displays the highest value for every subject (will be the same for every row of the subject).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

compare_table = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
    'day#': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'random#': [2,5,1,6, 4, 5, 9, 3],
     'highest_random#': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}, columns=[
    'id', 'day#','random#','highest_random#'])

for element in list(compare_table['id'].unique()):
        highest_random = max(compare_table.loc[compare_table.loc[:,'id']==element, 'random#'])
        compare_table.loc[compare_table.loc[:,'id']==element, 'highest_random#']= highest_random
```

Comment: `compare_table.groupby('id')['random#'].transform('max')
` try to search before ask ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by `max` or `map` aggregated `Series`:

```
compare_table['highest_random#1'] = compare_table.groupby('id')['random#'].transform('max')

#a bit slowier alternative
s = compare_table.groupby('id')['random#'].max()
compare_table['highest_random#2'] = compare_table['id'].map(s)
print (compare_table)
   id  day#  random#  highest_random#  highest_random#1  highest_random#2
0   1     1        2              5.0                 5                 5
1   1     2        5              5.0                 5                 5
2   1     3        1              5.0                 5                 5
3   2     1        6              6.0                 6                 6
4   2     2        4              6.0                 6                 6
5   3     1        5              9.0                 9                 9
6   3     2        9              9.0                 9                 9
7   3     3        3              9.0                 9                 9
```

Comment: awesome thanks man, I appreciate it! I was searching for this for a while but it can be hard to find info when unsure of how to ask the question in a general way.

Comment: @GarrettEickelberg - I am curious about timings, so give me some time for add it.

Comment: went from 5min to 5sec processing time, thanks a lot!

Comment: @GarrettEickelberg - Super, glad can help!